# Gemfire region persistent issue

Tags: region, gemfire, geode

Currently I'm facing this issue after implementing SecurityManager. A simple gist of what I did was, create an object with populated values if an user logins. If another user logins,  I would overwrite one specific variable in the previous user's object. Then I proceed to stop server and starts it again. When I check through pulse, my two objects are there as expected but that one specific variable reverted to its initial value before the second user logins. It's the same for subsequent users. Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: I think some code would help. Can you boil the problem down to a small sample?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I found a bug with my codes. Apparently, after retrieving the object from the region, I have to region.put(retrieved object's key, the retrieved object) back instead of just object.setVariable(). Not sure why it works previously when the class used the interface Authenticator. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Requires region.put(retrieved object's key, the retrieved object) back instead of just object.setVariable().